# Unions and sharing data fields(C++)

Tags: c++, sdl, shared, unions

In the API documentation of SDL for the [Union event](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event) it says that the the field type is shared among all the event(objects) in the union,how is this possible?

also for example this is perfectly legal

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){

  if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){


   cout << "key down" << endl;
  }
```

and this is also works which logically makes more sense to me ,but I'm not sure how the first is even legal

```
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){

   if(event.key.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){


       cout << "key down" << endl;
   }
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer (using the checkmark), once you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A union has the potential to represent *one* out of *multiple possible* types/structures.

```
union {
  int i;
  float f;
  char c;
};
```

In the example above, the memory which holds the union can represent an `int` *or* a `float` *or* a `char`.  But it can only be *one* of those things; they are mututally exclusive.  The union overlaps the underlying bytes used by each member in order to save space, and assumes you will know how to correctly interpret it.

(Side note: to accommodate this, the 'size' of the union - the cloud of bytes in which the union is stored - must be large enough to hold the largest possible type defined in the union.  In this case, int or float could each be 4 bytes, so the union will be at least 4 bytes.)

One neat side-effect of this overlapping memory 'trick'; if a union describes multiple `struct` members, then they can share common fields.

Example:

```
union {
  struct {
    int type;
    int i;
  } OPTION_INT;

  struct {
    int type;
    float f;
  } OPTION_FLOAT;

  struct {
    int type;
    char c;
  } OPTION_CHAR;
};
```

Okay, neat; the union could represent any one of three possible structs.  Notice, though; they all contain the exact same first member - `type`.  Because of the way the memory is 'overlapped', the OPTION_INT `type` member shares the same memory as the OPTION_FLOAT and OPTION_CHAR `type` members.  Thus, no matter which option is correct, the `type` member should always exist.  This is possible because they all define the `type` field as the very first member.

Comment: wow thanks,amazing detailed answer much appreciated =) ,that makes a lot of sense

Comment: While the neat trick is probably going to work, it doesn't have to in C++ and is not guaranteed to work. For best results [stick to POD types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) and if it absolutely must work, even in the case of the compiler designers doing the unexpected, remove `type` from the inner `struct`s and wrap the `union` in a `struct` that contains `type`.

Comment: I question that statement; it's *definitely* guaranteed in C - there is a special clause about common initial members of a union in the language specification - but I don't know the C++ specification closely enough to know if this clause is missing.  My understanding was that C is a complete subset of C++, which would suggest the same guarantee exists in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Unions -- gotta love'em :) There's no real equivalent in Java, so many Java developers find them peculiar. A union is conceptually a little like an abstract class -- a single union can have different kinds of data packed into it. The data types often have a sort of parent-child inheritance relationship -- they do in the case -- but they aren't required to. It's not unusual, for example, for see a union that consist of an integer and double -- in such a case this isn't a data structure that contains an integer *and* a double, but one that contains *either* an integer or a double, in some specific chunk of memory. The type which is actually in use has to be determined at run-time.

In this case, the SDL_Event union models a number of different kinds of event. The first field, `type` indicates how the rest of the data should be interpreted. If the type is `SDL_KEYDOWN`, then the union should be interpreted as a structure of type SDL_KeyboardEvent. The first field of SDL_KeyboardEvent is also `type` -- which makes some sense, since it's packed into the same space as the "base" SDL_Event. You can think of `type` (a little) like an attribute of the "base" SDL_Event, that can be (sort of) inherited by the specific sub-types. I'm being a bit waffly here, because the analogy is not really all that strong.

In any case, the compiler will ensure that SDL_Event is large enough to store any of the different structures it is defined to contain. Apart from `type` the specific structures `SDL_DropEvent`, `SDL_KeyboardEvent`, etc, don't have a lot in common, as can be seen by looking at their definitions.

In Java AWT, event classes perform almost exactly the same role as the SDL_Event union does in SDL with C.

Comment: Thanks Kevin superb detailed answer =) that makes sense now,yeah that is quite different to Java but I think that's pretty cool concept